# futuretap / FTLocationSimulator Testing current Location In iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

FTLocationSimulator allows simulating Core Location in the iPhone simulator on the desktop. It sends fake Core Location updates taken from a KML file that describes a predefined route.

in this link 
https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator

i cannot understand what i must do in step 6 & 7 ? 
Any One Can Help Me ?

Answer (score 0):

For 6:
There is this constant which says how often (in seconds) will this class call your delegate's `didUpdateToLocation` method. It is adjustable, the default is 0.3 (seconds) as you can see.

For 7:
It is a kml included, a trip from Cupertino to San Francisco. It's long enough, you can simply replace this if you want test with your own trip.

Comment: you change the 0.3 to whatever value you want and rerun the app in simulator